# ImageJ: Image registration of 2 multi-page TIF images using 1 layer as reference

Tags: image-processing, alignment, imagej, image-registration

I am looking for a way to register 2 TIF images (no stack, just 4 color channels).

image1: L1,L2,L3,L4

image2: L1*,L5,L6,L7

Layer 1 is used as reference layer between the images.
So I'd like to calculate the transformation matrix using L1 and L1* and apply the transformation to L5,L6,L7 of image2.

Which plugin can do this, preferentially with batch capabilities? The ones I've found (e.g. turboreg, stackreg, bunwarpJ) are either not able to handle non-stacks or "color" images or both and most of them can't handle batches.

Thanks a lot,
Mario

Comment: Unfortunately, I had exactly the same problem as you. Therefore, I had to get the turboreg source code, and modify the main method in order to deal with batches. A color image can be seen as images, so one channel per image. Sorry, but I did it for a company and I cannot share it :-(

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. Just for my understanding, you performed the color image registration with turboreg out of the box, but had to edit the source code to make it work with batches, right?

Comment: Yes. I had to do the registration for thousands of gray level images, according to the central image, so each image was registered according to the previous. Then an other time, I had to register the same images (thousands again) according to a given image. Finally, same work. For your color images, you can decompose the colors

Comment: OK, will see how far I get ;)
Cheers!

Comment: Let me know, I may lead you if you are stuck

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll hold you to your word ;) Have a nice day!